# How to use RestSharp Portable 3.0 in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, cross-platform, restsharp

I'm working on a mobile app with Xamarin and I need to use a librairy for webservices which works on Android, iOS and Windows phone !

I checked a long time on google, and I think the best one is RestSharp Portable 3.0.1.

First I launch Visual studio and I click on file - new - project - visual C# - Mobile APPS and then BLACK APP (Xamarin.forms Portable).

After this, I got a full project with :

```
1 - My project (HelloWorld here for example)
2 - My project.android
3 - My project.iOS
4 - My project.WinPhone
```

I click on the 1 and then I add the RestSharp Portable references via Nuget and it's okay.

Now, i'm trying to use it but I cannot find anything on google about it, I don't know if it's because it's a new version but I have nothing on it.

So the question is : WHat is the best using WebServices into Xamarin for a cross app ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: Did you happen to see [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl) while searching? It's smaller than RestSharp and not nearly as feature-rich, but if you're calling JSON-based services in a Xamarin app it might be all you need. I'm the author and I'm happy to answer any questions.

Comment: @ToddMenier I'm on your website looking how it's works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use RestSharp with no issues.
Here is the [component link](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/).
And here is their [website](http://restsharp.org/).

It doesn't say that the component supports windows phone but I'm sure you can port it.

Comment: I cannot add RestSharp to my project, or i don't get how to use it, but with Nugget I got a error ...

Comment: @Nicolas_LeBot did you find any solution? VS 2015 doesn't install from nuget. but there is RestSharp.Portable  want to be sure.

Comment: Hey @NuriYILMAZ, I don't know about VS 2015. Actually my project has been stopped so I didn't coninue working on it. Sorry I cannot help you.